# Missing notifications in lock screen after update to Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications

After upgrading my Galaxy S5 to Android 5.0, notifications now are not showing in the top bar when the screen is locked. I understand that there is an option to show notifications in lock screen, from the sound and notification settings, but these still do not show in the top bar of the lock screen, but rather as annoying white boxes. Is there any way to bring this feature back or even an app that can do this? I don't understand why several useful features have been removed in the new update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to tell you, there is no way to get them back to the status bar. You can only have them shown as you mentioned in your question. On Google I found a lot of discussions about this. However, I couldn't find a solution anywhere on the internet. Hope Google will give an option for this in later updates for android. I also miss it. And the "contents hidden" is useless. Why couldn't they make that option restore the icons to the statusbar...

Hope my answer helps!

Comment: That is just ridiculous- yet another feature that actually made things easier taken away. Does anyone know of any apps that may bring this feature back? I know there are lots of related apps out there, but anything that allows notifications to be shown in the status bar on lock screen?

Comment: @wb1 at the time of writing this, there is no app that can restore the notification icons on the lockscreen. And if my answer helps you, could you accept it for the benefit of others? Thanks.